# Subtree cost higher than threshold not running in parallel

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a query running with Estimated Subtree Cost much higher than my Cost Threshold of Parallelism, however the query does not run in parallel. I wouldn't say that it is a cached plan, once SQL Server should force a plan recompilation when the threshold is changed.  Am I right ?

This is the plan:
 https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rya1BFKfe

This is the plan of the view it is based upon:
  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1CBcKtMl

Comment: Is [ViewStatementDetailsGroupByUserFuture!] a view? If so, could you supply the code that creates this view? I suspect you may have something like a scalar function in there (which will kill the parallelism) but can't check without the code.

Comment: Try having a look [at this part of the presentation](https://youtu.be/zh90ukQPgLo?t=22m27s), you might find something useful. I haven't encountered problems with parallelism in my day to day work, but I remember they had some interesting causes for a query not going parallel.

Comment: @RichBenner It seems to be a view, but I don't see it calling a scalar function inside the plan.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/sql-server-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu perhaps, we're just guessing at this point though. Until there's more information we're in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. @Rich, you're right, there are a few SUM functions in the view, but the funny thing is that I've seen this plan getting parallel before. Also when executing in test environment, I get the expected plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByouYFKfe 

Radu I'll take a look at the video, thank you.

Comment: @EvertonBarciela SUM shouldn't stop parallelism on it's own. If there's a difference between dev and live are you sure that MAXDOP isn't set to 1 (assuming you've checked the cost threshold is correct)?

Comment: This is the plan of the view: 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1CBcKtMl

Comment: @RichBenner Yes, MAXDOP is set to 8.

Comment: @EvertonBarciela the fact that you're getting differences between dev and live (with parallelism) means that this isn't likely an issue with your code but rather a setting somewhere. It would be worth going through all of these settings again to ensure that they match across both systems.

Comment: This is weird, all server configurations match between dev and live, and we haven't applied anything on the live server recently.

Comment: Did you try to enforce recompilation?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, Just try it and I still get the same plan.

Comment: This was an interesting article on this topic.  

Consider OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649)

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx